# Ayuda con Error ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

Tags: oracle, ubuntu

Vengo a presentarles un tema interesante para tratar con ustedes resulta que instalé `Oracle Database 11g Release 2` en `Ubuntu 14.04` que me costó bastante pero al parecer lo logré. Pero me encontré con un inconveniente al momento de querer conectar al `sqlplus` con el usuario SYS como SYSDBA me salta el siguiente error:

> Error ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

Por favor si alguien me podría ayudar con esto les agradecería bastante!

---

[image]
este fue el error que me dio durante la instlacion que fueron como 6 veces el mismo error le di en siguiente pensando que podria solucionar luego pero hasta ahora no lo consigo

Comment: Intenta cambiando permisos a el directorio de  instalación(por ejemplo :cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin ) : chmod 6751 oracle
ls -ltr oracle

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero sigue el error durante la instalación me daba el mismo error

Comment: los parametros de kernel estan mal o bien los persmisos!
recuerda que el usuario debe ser oracle:oinstall y debes settear el setenforce 0

Comment: Revisa esto http://www.dadbm.com/how-to-fix-ora-12547-tns-lost-contact-when-try-to-connect-to-oracle/

Answer (score 0):

Alguna vez me salio ese error y era que la version del SO no estaba certificada para la version de oracle, lo mas probable es que falten librerias o que sean diferentes a lo que oracle espere (Mas nuevas o mas viejas). Yo preferiria irme por una version de Oracle linux, creo que la 6.5 es la indicada para 11g. 
Igual por tu link en la imagen menciona Ubuntu 12.04 Igual trata instalando esa version.